# Wireless Won't Connect in 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, 14.04

I'm still very new to Ubuntu and I need help resolving an issue with my wireless. My connection shows up clearly as "dlink" but ubuntu simply won't connect to it. It worked fine downloading updates during the install. Could you please help?

Here is the output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

And here's... `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:e374 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Ouput of `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69160  0 
bnep                   19624  2 
bluetooth             395423  10 bnep,rfcomm
joydev                 17381  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46207  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    61438  1 
uvcvideo               80885  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
rts5139               335409  0 
arc4                   12608  2 
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
rtl8188ee              89601  0 
kvm_intel             143060  0 
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8188ee
rtlwifi                63475  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
kvm                   451511  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
mac80211              626489  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8188ee
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
cryptd                 20359  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
psmouse               102222  0 
serio_raw              13462  0 
lpc_ich                21080  0 
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_hda_intel          52355  3 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69238  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
i915                  783485  3 
drm_kms_helper         52758  1 i915
video                  19476  1 i915
drm                   302817  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
mac_hid                13205  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
mei_me                 18627  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
mei                    82274  1 mei_me
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
ahci                   25819  2 
libahci                32168  1 ahci
alx                    32452  0 
mdio                   13807  1 alx
```

Output of `rfkill list all`

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `nm-tool`

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8188ee
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        48:D2:24:CD:05:6B

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    ATT496:          Infra, 20:E5:64:A1:5D:B0, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
    ATT928:          Infra, 38:6B:BB:0A:9C:70, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
    ATT048:          Infra, 58:56:E8:8B:21:F0, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
    dlink:           Infra, 00:1C:F0:C0:42:7F, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 97


- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            alx
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:8C:FA:6D:59:B8

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.103
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I think this is an old bug, which affects some wireless adapters: When wired connection is enabled, wireless will disconnect after some seconds (or the way round, I don't remember exactly). To solve this you have to disable the connection you don't want to use.
Greetings